# Do Items Despawn Over Time?

Tags: borderlands-2

I plan on spawning Death Trap and letting him get kills for a long period of time for exp. Will any items that are dropped despawn over time (pc)?

Comment: This is likely something that may be system specific.  What platform are you playing on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most items will despawn fairly quickly (within minutes, upon leaving the map or when tons more stuff spawns elsewhere), except for quest items and rare loot (green or better). Green stuff definitely sticks around longer than white, but it does seem to eventually despawn when off-map.  Items of blue rarity and higher *appear* to either have unlimited or greatly extended lifespans, even when leaving a map.

So you can definitely be confident that some of the rarer stuff will remain, but I'm unsure if *all* of it will, as there's likely a despawn on green/rarer stuff as well so the game doesn't crash if you somehow piled up hundreds of them. This is all based on (300 hours of) casual observation though, I'm unsure of the exact specifics.

Comment: You say that green loot despawns quickly and then say that it sticks around for a while. I'm not very knowledgeable in this area so maybe I just don't understand

Comment: @Kecoey, the meaning is that all items *except* quest items, and rare loot (green or better), will despawn quickly.  Basically, that comes down to white items, ammo, cash, health, shield boosters, and other little things.  Does this also apply to customization skins, Ben?

Comment: Sidenote: When the Warrior blocks legendary loot with its corpse, people advise to leave the area and come back. This implies Legendaries can survive at least two map changes and the time needed to clear Hero's Pass.

Comment: @OrcJMR I've had legendaries survive more or less an entire hour+ game session. If they do despawn I don't think it's based on how many maps you pass (I do think greens will eventually despawn map-based, but more than 2 transitions)

Comment: Is this for the PC version?

Comment: @Batophobia yeah. Come to think of it Console games might burn items sooner because of lower memory, but I imagine the system is similar.